# set product status programatically

Tags: product, magento2, status

I have idea we can set product status using following code in magento 1.x.but I’m not able to identify in magento 2.0 beta. i'm spending lot of time to search status.php file. i find following file.but no use.

> magento2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Source/Status.php

```
$productid=10;// product id which you want to change status; 
    $storeid=1 
    Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($productid, $storeid, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`

Declare a dependency on it by adding it to your constructor

```
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

Then you can update the status and save it back with the following code in your method

```
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $this->productRepository->save($product);
```

Comment: thanks for ur response.status is website scope.how to set website wise?