# How to set a start and end time for Product Status

Tags: magento2, products, status, enable-disable

Am I able to set a start and end time for product status?

I'm running an ecom store and would like to know if I can set a date & time for product to enable/disable.

For example, if I am scheduling sending an email to send out at 6am, and I would also like to schedule products to enable at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a bespoke console script and time it to run on cron schedule.  Inside the console script you would build a product collection based on the required criteria to select the required product(s).  Then update status.

This should get you started with a console script

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/220791/70343

This should get you started with a product collection

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/196956/70343

This should give you an idea on how to update product status

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/65669/70343